# ionic 4 - cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-sockets-udp

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, udp, cordova-plugins, ionic4

I'm trying to build an ionic app for android and ios.
In this app I need to send and receive udp packets to the server.
For that I trying to use https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-sockets-udp

but i keep getting this error while running on a real device android device:

```
core.js:9110 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
```

My code that causes this error is:

```
async broadcasting(messageSend)
{

    this.platform.ready().then(
        (readySource) => {
    var udp = require('udp-packet');
    chrome = window['chrome'];
    if(readySource == 'cordova')
    {
      const pack = udp.encode({
        sourceIp: '10.0.0.1',
        sourcePort: 58936,
        destinationIp: '85.214.60.74',
        destinationPort: 7810,
        data: new Buffer(messageSend)
      });

      (<any>window).chrome.sockets.udp.bind(123445, pack,'85.214.60.74',7810, function(result){
        console.log("result bind",result);
      });
      chrome.sockets.udp.send(123445, pack,'85.214.60.74',7810, function(result){
        console.log("result send",result);
      });
      chrome.sockets.udp.onReceive.addListener(function(result){
        console.log("result listener",result);
      });
    }
        });
}
```

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding that I only had tcp plugin installed, I had to run "cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-sockets-udp" to make it work.